# Plivo API endpoint Exception In Initializer error

Tags: android, android-studio, plivo

```
03-24 10:51:22.425 20219-20219/com.mordred.call E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.backend.PlivoAppCallback.<init>(PlivoAppCallback.java:114)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.BackendListener.<init>(BackendListener.java:28)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.initLib(Endpoint.java:150)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.java:47)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.newInstance(Endpoint.java:63)
                                                                  at com.mordred.call.PstnActivity.<init>(PstnActivity.java:46)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.plivo.endpoint.backend.plivoJNI.swig_module_init:()V
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.backend.plivoJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.backend.plivoJNI.<clinit>(plivoJNI.java:108)
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.backend.PlivoAppCallback.<init>(PlivoAppCallback.java:114) 
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.BackendListener.<init>(BackendListener.java:28) 
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.initLib(Endpoint.java:150) 
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.java:47) 
                                                                  at com.plivo.endpoint.Endpoint.newInstance(Endpoint.java:63) 
                                                                  at com.mordred.call.PstnActivity.<init>(PstnActivity.java:46) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

I am using the plivo api, but when i open an activity, i get that error above, i know its coming from my endpoint instantiation, i.e i cannot do this

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.newInstance(true, this);
```

but i do not know what to do instead and i do not know what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

What's the processor architecture of the android phone that you're testing on? This error occurs when the libpjplivo.so file is incompatible with the processor architecture.

Please raise a ticket our [support portal](https://support.plivo.com/) and we can help you debug this.